# Having some trouble compiling Bourbon with VS 2013, and Web Essentials

Tags: sass, bourbon

I'm having trouble compiling _bourbon.scss.

I have to comment out the following, in order for it to compile successfully.

```
@import "helpers/font-source-declaration";
@import "helpers/linear-angle-parser";
@import "helpers/linear-gradient-parser";
@import "helpers/linear-positions-parser";
@import "helpers/linear-side-corner-parser";
@import "helpers/radial-arg-parser";
@import "helpers/radial-positions-parser";
@import "helpers/radial-gradient-parser";
@import "helpers/render-gradients";
@import "helpers/shape-size-stripper";*/
@import "css3/keyframes";
@import "addons/padding";
@import "addons/position";
@import "addons/prefixer";
```

The error I am receiving is:
Something went wrong reaching: [127.0.0.1.... long path to file]

I attempted on Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 & 4 with no luck.

Comment: - Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they?
- How are you compiling the Sass? Keep in mind that Bourbon has certain [Sass version reuiqrements](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon#requirements), so maybe Visual Studio comes packaged with an out-of-date version?

Comment: It was giving me a syntax error. I was able to get it to work by installing Mindscape Workbench. Not sure how to check the version of the SASS compiler running with Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there an error?  What is the error?

Comment: @cimmanon It was "Something went wrong reaching: [http://127.0.0.1.... long path to file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing around for a while, and trying a bunch of different plugins I finally got it to work with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Web Essentials.

The trick was going into the SASS settings of Web Essentials:
Tools --> Options --> Web Essentials --> SASS

and changing "Use Ruby Runtime" to "True".

Comment: Thank you, this was affecting me a great deal - you spared me long hours of searching!